# double datatype is not assigning large value

Tags: double, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign a large value to a double datatype for example

double **someValue** = **36028797018963967D**;

but the problem is, when I debug the value of variable **someValue**, it becomes **36028797018963968D** and I cant figure out why.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: What language, java? How are you debugging it? Show us your code, please. I think that you should always get engineering notation when you debug, print this, in java, so if you're formatting it, then your formatting may be wrong. Try using a BigDecimal instead.

Comment: @EngineerDollery This behaviour is expected in most languages that use 64 bit floating point.

Comment: this is in c#, i am debugging this line by line in Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

Both of these numbers are the same in 64 bit floating point. What gets printed is an artifact of the method used to print them. Try this:

```
assert(36028797018963967D == 36028797018963968D)
```

It works!